# I don't know why I'm getting syntax error while loading yaml

Tags: ansible

I want to update all software packages in the playbook using the following lines,

```
---
- name: First play

  hosts: all

  tasks:

     - name: Update all the current software packages on the system

       yum: name=* state=latest
```

but I keep receiving an error says there something wrong in the syntax.

```
The offending line appears to be:
- name: Update all the current software packages on the system
   yum: name=* state=latest
      ^ here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "yum" has an incorrect additional space before it, and "- name" needs to be in line with tasks. Try this:

```
---
- name: First play
  hosts: all

  tasks:
  - name: Update all the current software packages on the system
    yum:
      name: *
      state: latest
```

Comment: I've aligned them, but I'm still receiving the same error

Comment: and if you try not do it in one line and spit yum, name and state over three lines?
Such as on here: https://www.ansible.com/blog/getting-started-writing-your-first-playbook

Comment: I still receive an error, but this time is a different type. It says: ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

Comment: The hyphen in "- name" needs to be directly underneath the word tasks, you've tabbed it.

Comment: It's directly underneath it, and it's not tabbed.

Comment: Updated my answer, try that.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. It doesn't make sense, cause it looks like mine. thank you for your help

Comment: Differences could be as small as a single space. Try do a difference between mine and yours, so you know for future: https://www.diffchecker.com. Glad I could help.